# PostgreSQL, build compressed json depending group clause

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to build a json object which would be very easy to use in JS with no doublon key. For this, i've been searching an equivalent problem but it never  looks like mine...

I am doing this query :

```
SELECT type_bien, nature_mutation , option
FROM layer.dvf a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT value, option
    FROM form_select
    WHERE name = 'nature_mutation'
) b ON LOWER(a.nature_mutation) = LOWER(b.value)
WHERE option IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY type_bien, nature_mutation, option
order by type_bien, nature_mutation, option
```

Which give me this result :

```
type_bien           nature_mutation option
appartement         adjudication    Adjudication
appartement         echange         Échange
appartement         VEFA            VEFA
appartement         vente           Vente
dependance          adjudication    Adjudication
dependance          echange         Échange
dependance          VEFA            VEFA
dependance          vente           Vente
local_indus_comm    adjudication    Adjudication
local_indus_comm    echange         Échange
local_indus_comm    VEFA            VEFA
local_indus_comm    vente           Vente
maison              adjudication    Adjudication
maison              echange         Échange
maison              VEFA            VEFA
maison              vente           Vente
terrain             adjudication    Adjudication
terrain             echange         Échange
terrain             Expropriation   Expropriation
terrain             vente           Vente
```

Here is some content from table **layer.dvf** :

```
TYPE_BIEN           NATURE_MUTATION
appartement         vente
appartement         VEFA
appartement         echange
appartement         adjudication
appartement         vente_TAB
dependance          vente
dependance          VEFA
dependance          echange
dependance          adjudication
local_indus_comm    adjudication
local_indus_comm    echange
local_indus_comm    VEFA
local_indus_comm    vente
local_indus_comm    vente_TAB
maison              vente_TAB
maison              vente
maison              VEFA
maison              echange
maison              adjudication
terrain             adjudication
terrain             echange
terrain             Expropriation
terrain             vente
terrain             vente_TAB
```

Here is some content from table **form_select** :

```
name                value               option
nature_mutation     echange             échange
nature_mutation     expropriation       Expropriation
nature_mutation     vefa                VEFA
nature_mutation     vente               Vente
nature_mutation     adjudication        Adjudication
nature_bien         maison              Maison
nature_bien         appartement         Appartement
nature_bien         local_indus_comm    Local industriel / commercial
nature_bien         dependance          Dépendance
nature_bien         terrain             Terrain
```

But I do not success to build this sort of result :

```
{
{
    "type_bien" : "appartement",
    "nature_mutation" : {
        {"value": "adjudication","option":"Adjudication"}, 
        {"value" : "echange","option" : "Échange"}, 
        {"value":"VEFA","option":"VEFA"}, 
        {"value":"vente","option":"Vente"}, 
}
{
    "type_bien" : "dependance",
    "nature_mutation" : {
        {"value":"adjudication","option":"Adjudication"}, 
        {"value":"echange","option":"Échange"}, 
        {"value":"VEFA","option":"VEFA"}, 
        {"value":"vente","option":"Vente"}
    }
}
...
```

But I don't even know if this is possible... Can someone give me a way to do this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: show the table you have in a text format.

Comment: I edited the post to show you a part of the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here i found my solution :

```
SELECT json_agg(result)
FROM (
    SELECT json_build_object(
        'type_bien', type_bien, 
        'nature_mutation', json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                'value', value, 
                'option', option
            )
        )
    ) as result
    FROM (
        SELECT type_bien, nature_mutation, value, option
        FROM layer.dvf d
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT value, option
            FROM form_select
        ) c ON LOWER(d.nature_mutation) = LOWER(c.value)
        WHERE option IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY type_bien, nature_mutation, value, option
        ORDER BY type_bien, nature_mutation
    ) b
    GROUP BY type_bien
) t
```

The second group by, permitted me to not duplicate "type_bien"

Answer (score 0):

build a json object with `json_build_object`. I first get json object for nature_mutation using `cte` and build json object for `type_bien` from `group by` column

```
with t as(
    select t1.type_bien, 
      json_agg(json_build_object('value', value, 'option', option)) AS nature_mutation
    from layer t1
    join form_select t2
    on lower(t1.nature_mutation) = lower(t2.value)
    group by 1)
select json_build_object('type_bien', type_bien, 'nature_mutation', nature_mutation) 
from t;
```

Comment: There is something missing cuz i get this :
{"type_bien" : "local_indus_comm", "nature_mutation" : [{"value" : "vente", "option" : "Vente"}, {"value" : "vente", "option" : "Vente"} ... ] }
{"type_bien" : "maison", "nature_mutation" : [{"value" : "vente", "option" : "Vente"}, {"value" : "vente",  ... }]